# Very New To Power Shell, Object Reference Error In Short Script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

First off, I'm very new to Power Shell (and scripting in general). I'm getting my feet wet by trying to write a simple script that will get all users with a certain manager, and then set them to a new manager. Currently, we do this manually in our AD and it can be time consuming.

However, with the script below I keep getting the following error:

*Set-ADUser : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:6 char:2
+     Set-ADUser -Identity $users -Manager jane.manager*

Here is my short script:

```
$users=Get-ADUser -Identity john.manager -Properties directreports | Select directreports

ForEach ($user in $users) {

    Set-ADUser -Identity $users -Manager jane.manager
}
```

Comment: Should that not be `$user` instead of `$users` ?

Comment: As per @t0mm13b... you are looping through each one of `$users`, calling the current item that you are processing `$user`, so you want to make sure that the `Set-ADUser` cmdlet is only operating on each (single) `$user` in turn.

Comment: Also, if you're new to this game (i.e. modifying Active Directory programmatically) for goodness sake use the `-WhatIf` and/or `-Confirm` switches on `Set-ADUser` until you are sure that nothing crazy will happen. you wouldn't want to set **everyone's** manager to be Jane? She'd soon be asking for a pay rise.

Comment: Thanks for catching the singular / plural issue!

Also, ha! I'm in a test environment, but it's nice to know there's a -WhatIf command! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your current script.

```
$users=Get-ADUser -Identity john.manager -Properties directreports | Select directreports
                                                   #                   ^
                                                   #                   |
                                                   # this creates 1 object with a 
                                                   # "directreports" property
```

`Set-ADUser` won't be able to recognize such an object. Since you want references to the `directReports` objects, expand it to a list of values with the `ExpandProperty` parameter:

```
$users=Get-ADUser -Identity john.manager -Properties directreports | Select -ExpandProperty directreports
```

The second problem appears to be a typo, inside the loop you refer to the `$users` collection that you're looping over, instead of the current `$user`:

```
$users=Get-ADUser -Identity john.manager -Properties directreports | Select -ExpandProperty directreports

foreach($user in $users){
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Manager jane.manager
}
```

---

If you're unsure what you're doing, heed [Charlie Joynt's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399670/very-new-to-power-shell-object-reference-error-in-short-script/44399942?noredirect=1#comment75799644_44399670) and use the `-WhatIf` switch parameter with `Set-ADUser`:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Manager jane.manager -WhatIf
```

Instead of making any changes, `Set-ADUser` will tell you what it was *going to do*, had you omitted `-WhatIf`

Comment: Ah. Thank-you Mr. Jessen. Was just typing the same answer as yours. My worry about what can happen to AD when you feed in bad data to `Set-ADUser` (see comment on original post) still stands. ;-)

Comment: @CharlieJoynt Oh, absolutely!

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm definitely closer as I'm not getting any errors. However, I'm not seeing the manager switch on the user I had previously set to "John." Will keep plucking away!